# passing struct pointers to functions c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

Should be a simple question, I have a struct

```
struct Foo{
    float *bar;
    Foo(){
        bar = 0;
    }
};
```

and a load function:

```
bool loadFoo(Foo *data){
    float nums[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    data->bar = nums;
    return true;
};
```

And I run it like this:

```
void main(){
    char data;
    Foo myFoo;
    loadFoo(&myFoo);
    std::cerr << sizeof(myFoo.bar) << "\n";
    std::cerr << myFoo.bar[0] << "\n";
    std::cerr << myFoo.bar[1] << "\n";
    std::cerr << myFoo.bar[2] << "\n";
    std::cerr << myFoo.bar[3];
    std::cin >> data;
};
```

and the output is 4 bytes for the sizeof(myFoo->bar) I thought by passing the struct to the method I could modify data->bar and since bar is, float *bar; I could make it an array since I cant specify that bar is an array because its an 'unknown size' when loaded. (when implemented the program will read in values from a file) This works fine with non pointer variables but its the pointer that I can't seem to understand.

How do I make it so that when I pass the struct I can modify the variable pointer?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the question, and what problem are you trying to solve? Your `loadFoo` function is quite broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like you've specified, but the exact implementation you've given will encounter undefined behavior.

```
bool loadFoo(Foo *data){
    // Create an array of 4 floats ON THE STACK.
    float nums[4] = {0,1,2,3};
    // point data->bar at the above slice of stack.
    data->bar = nums;
    return true;
    // abandon the piece of stack we're pointing at.
}
```

You might want to look into std::vector as a growable way of storing runtime sizes arrays, or you will need to allocate backing store for the destination floats, e.g.

```
data->bar = new float[4];
```

and free it when you are done with it

```
delete data->bar;
```

That said; it would seem more elegant to do these operations as members of Foo.

```
#include <vector>
// #include <algorithm>   // (for the std::copy option)

class Foo
{
    std::vector<float>  m_floats;

public:
    Foo() : m_floats() {}
    void loadFloats()
    {
        m_floats = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    }
    // or load them from someplace else
    void loadFloats(float* srcFloats, size_t numFloats)
    {
        m_floats.clear();
        m_floats.reserve(numFloats);

        // copy by hand:
        for (size_t i = 0; i < numFloats; ++i) {
            m_floats.push_back(srcFloats[i]);
        }

        // or just:
        // std::copy(srcFloats, srcFloats + numFloats, m_floats);
    }
};
```

Comment: That was my next consideration, changing from struct to class and adding a method. This might actually be what I go with given some spare time.

Comment: @JayPC there is really no difference between `class` and `struct` in C++. They are essentially interchangeable. The only difference is default access of members and base classes.

Comment: Added the missing "public" :)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the problem but let me guess - it crashes and/or doesn't yield the result you expect. The reason for that is assigning a pointer to a local variable in the line `data->bar = nums;` Here you link your `data->bar` to a `nums` array which is allocated on stack and is freed when you exit `loadFoo`. The result is a dangling pointer inside your `Foo` object.

You can solve this in different ways. The most straightforward would be to use a constructor with size parameter - this will solve your `unkonwn size` issue. You'll need to explicitly allocate memory for the `data->bar` and *copy* the data into the allocated space (of course, it will require to free it when not in use anymore). Same effect can be achieved by using your `loadFoo` func but using internal language features (constructor/destructor) is much cleaner.

Comment: *facepalm* I forgot that after the method was finished, the local variable would be freed from memory. I understand having the Foo(size) constructor but unfortunately this is part of a bigger project that I change a few parts of the same struct in different locations so by the time I get to needing to loadFoo() Its already been instantiated. But this solves my mental roadblock.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `loadFoo` you can have constructor

```
struct Foo{
    float *bar;
    Foo( int size){
        bar = new float[size];  //allocate memory
        //... Initialize bar
    }
    ~Foo() { delete bar;}
};
```

OR using [**`initializer_list`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
#include <initializer_list>

struct Foo{
    float *bar;
    Foo( std::initializer_list<float> l){
        bar = new float[l.size()];  //allocate memory
        std::initializer_list<float> ::iterator it = l.begin();
        size_t i=0;
        for(;it!=l.end();++it,++i)
          bar[i] = *it;
    }
    ~Foo() { delete bar;}
};
```

Also, make sure you follow [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)

Comment: ... which probably requires a destructor.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, Its a small piece of a bigger project and by the time i actually call `loadFoo()` I have already Called the constructor and defaulted all the variables since I modify a different variable in the struct much earlier. I'll look into seeing if I can load the object from file sooner, so that I can pass it with the constructor.